# Wordpress stripping HTML code from some captions in jQuery Lightbox

Tags: wordpress, lightbox2, captions

The issue is occurring on this site: http://jessicasilvermangallery.com/exhibitions/dashiell-manley/

I am including captions with 
 and  tags for all the images.

When they are clicked the open in a light box and some honor the HTML and other strip the HTML.

It is very strange and i cannot figure out why it occurs to some images an not others.

It seems it may have to do with portrait vs. landscape orientation.

Can anyone offer any insight as to why this is happening and how I could fix it?

Comment: noticing this is a wordpress site. can you verify the content was entered in the exact same way? I noticed the issue between Another other (arms) and It and others (arms)

Comment: No Both are formatted the same: `<i>Another other (arms)</i><br>
Enamel, canvas, dye, wood, copper<br>
48 x 36 inches<br>
2015` and `<i>It and others (arms)</i><br>
Enamel, brass, dyed linen, gouache, watercolor, lacquer, graphite, plexiglass, wood, stainless steel, steel<br>
Painting – 48 x 60 inches, Entire structure – 96 x 72 inches<br>
2015`